# php and mysql different time in same timezone

Tags: php, mysql, time, timezone

I'm checking time with the php (carbon).
It gives me:

```
object(Carbon\Carbon)#16622 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2017-11-23 02:51:30.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

Also, I'm checking mysql timezone and time.
It gives me:

```
mysql> SELECT @@system_time_zone;
+--------------------+
| @@system_time_zone |
+--------------------+
| UTC                |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2017-11-22 21:49:27 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Same timezones, different time, hm.
So, question is - what is the preferable way to fix this difference? 
And why this difference is happening?

Comment: Interesting. So what's your question?

Comment: I've updated question

Comment: What timezone do you establish the Mysql connection from? UTC-0500?